# How would one reverse the following jQuery animation after it completes and is displayed for 10 seconds?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

This works great to bring the div into the window, however, when I try to put any functions that would reverse the animation (and make the panel retreat the same way it came in, nothing happens lol... I am new to this jQuery stuff. I'm sure I'm just doing something wrong.

What I would like to have happen is have the window slide in (like the current code does), then after it is in view for like 10 seconds, have the window retreat the same way it came in.

jQuery:

```
<!-- Live Support Slide-In -->
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    // Store our panel into a variable.
    var $myPanel = $("#live-chat");

    // Get the height of the panel dynamically.
    var $myPanelHeight = parseInt($myPanel.height());

    // Immediately set the opacity to 0 - to hide it and set its bottom to minus its height.
    $myPanel.css({ "opacity" : 0, "bottom" : "-" + $myPanelHeight + "px" });

    // Set a timeout for the panel to slide and fade in.
    setTimeout(function() {

        $myPanel.animate({

            // The CSS properties we want to animate (opacity and bottom position).
            opacity: 1,
            bottom: '0'

        }, 2000, function() {

            // Animation complete. 
            // Here is where I tried putting an additional setTimeout(). Wouldn't help much, because I can't seem to reverse the animation.

                });

    }, 5000); // 30 seconds in MS

}); 
</script>
<!-- End Live Support Slide-In -->
```

HTML:

```
  <h1 class="tech" style="">Need Help?</h1>
  <p style="font-size:14px;">Don't worry! Our sales team is just one-click away. If you have questions regarding a product, your order status, etc. just click the link below and start a Live Chat session now.</p>
  <a style="display:block; text-align:right; font-weight:bold; font-size:14px;" href="#">+ Chat with a salesman</a>
  <div id="no-thanks-close"><img src="/images/components/no-thanks-close.png" alt="Close this Window..." /></div>

 </div>
</div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! :) Thanks in advance guys!

Answer (score 0):

Literally do the opposite. Opacity to 100% and then maybe capture where the original "top" position was and save it as a variable outside of the function then you do a call to a function that is the opposite of what you have now using top instead of bottom using the caught variable as your top position and in theory it should work, may need a bit of tweaking outside of that, but should generally be that easy.

Comment: Definitely trying to do it this way. Logically, that's what I figured would get it done properly. For some reason, it seemed to not trigger on .setTimeout when I placed the function in the area mentioned in the source... Appreciate you taking the time to respond!